# How to access FileReader element outside reader.onload method

Tags: javascript, html, dom, file-upload, filereader

I have file upload option in my html file

```
<input type="file" id="myFile1">
<input type="file" id="myFile2">
```

I am using FileReader in Javascript and pushing the values into an array. Here files array has all the value of files read from the file input html.

```
 var count = files.length;
  var formValues= []; 

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(myfile) {
      return function(event) {
        formValues.push(event.target.result); 
      }
    })(file);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

Here the values are added to the array, formValues. Now I need to do few other modifications to this array and send it to the controller.

I am looping through the formValues to access the file value which was set inside reader.onload.

```
for (var i = 0; i < formValues.length; i++)
{
   console.log (formValues[i]);
}
```

If I try to access this value, it is not going inside the loop, but if I have a break point set in browser, it is going inside loop. I know, in order to use formValues, I should be using it inside the reader.onload method. Since formValues has the value of file, why I am not able to access the value if I loop through this array? I need to access this array outside to add few more items to this array apart from file value.

Comment: Could this be a racing situation? Your file reader is async. When are you trying to access `formValues`?

Comment: I am making sure that files are read completely and then only accessing the array in another place. When I check the file size, before the for loop, it has right size and value. But I am not sure, why it is not going inside for loop on a normal processing without using any debugger.

Comment: `var i = 0; b < formValues.length; i++` is this a typo are your actual code? Because `b` isn't anything.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I have figured out the issue. I think I was trying get the value before the file reader has completed reading the file. I had a flag defined and the made sure that the flag is true before looping through the formValues